# Issue with connecting to SQL Server 2017 for Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux

I have installed SQL Server 2017 on Linux Ubuntu together with SQL Command Line Tools.

Instantly after setting up and normal configuration I am unable to connect to it using the command line tools.

I am getting the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fix the issue by reinstalling the SQL Server 2017 on my Debian machine.

Microsoft instructions are for Ubuntu not Debian but the only error I was getting on Debian was about OpenSSL which I solved it using the following answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/930712/installation-problems-with-ms-sql-server-for-linux

Now it works perfectly on my Debian machine.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

- [Configure a Windows Firewall for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

Specifically:

> [Can not connect to MS SQL from Ubuntu sqlcmd
>   client](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/470)
>
> The fix for letting the Ubuntu client connect was to set "Listen to
>   All" to No in the SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server
>   Network Configuration > Protocols for [instance name]. And under IP
>   Address change 127.0.0.1 to the [ip] used to connect. Don't forget to
>   restart the SQL Server!
>
> Other tip: check your firewall (or temporaly disable it for testing).
>   Also allow remote connections in SQL Server properties > Connections.
>   See above posts.

Comment: My SQL Server is on Linux not the client. I am using SQL Server 2017 for Linux and it doesn't allow me to connect to it due to the mentioned error.

Comment: OK: look here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/252.  It appears to be the same Error  0x2746, the problem was TLS 1.2 support.  The workaround was to use a different driver (Sybase driver, instead of MSSQL).  See also [Troubleshoot SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems that I can connect using JDBC. Is there anyway we can make other apps working without using JDBC? Such as Azure Data Studio. ?